# Scala "functional" way to convert sequence with 'bad nesting" to well-formed XML

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

Apologies if this is a FAQ, I did not find it anywhere.  It is probably a newbie Scala and/or functional programming question.  I have lots of Java and OO experience, but I am new to Scala and FP.

Lets say I have a list that perhaps has:

a, b, b, c1, b, d, c2, d, a, ce, b, a, c1, b, ce, a, b

Now I'm going to process this list and return an XML tree (scala.xml.NodeSeq or whatever).  The tricky part is I need to replace any cases of c<n> with a span that encloses any following items, up to the next ce.  Further complicating things is nesting must be handled, but any "ce" items encountered need to close out all pending  tags.

So I want to get something like this out:

```
<a/>
<b/>
<b/>
<span style="style1">
  <b/>
  <d/>
  <span style="style2">
     <d/>
     <a/>
  </span>
</span>
<b/>
<a/>
<span style="style1">
  <b/>
</span>
<a/>
<b/>
```

This is in Scala, and I would prefer to do this in a "purely functional way", and using Scala best practices.  I'm quite frustrated, I cannot get my head around this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am on my phone right now and not able to provide a real answer. But  until someone else answers let me hint. You should call foldLeft on that list. This will allow you to collapse multiple elements into single elements as the list is traversed.

Comment: Will the list entries be Strings, or are you just using a, b, etc as placeholders for some other data type?  Also, will the data be well formed? Could you get a c3 following a c1 for example, or two c2's in succession? And will there always be intermediate values between cN's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recursion for the win:

```
  import scala.xml._
  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  val list = List("a", "b", "b", "c1", "b", "d", "c2", "d", "a", "ce", "b", "a", "c1", "b", "ce", "a", "b")

  case class Processor(value: NodeSeq = Nil, rest: List[String] = Nil, isSub: Boolean = false)

  @tailrec
  def toXml(processor: Processor): Processor = 
    processor.rest match {
      case head::tail if(head == "ce") =>   
        if(processor.isSub) Processor(processor.value, processor.rest)        
        else toXml(Processor(processor.value, tail))

      case head::tail if(head.startsWith("c")) => 
        val result = toXml(Processor(Nil, tail, true)) 
        toXml(processor.copy(value = processor.value ++ <span>{result.value}</span>, rest = result.rest))  

      case head::tail => toXml(processor.copy(value = processor.value ++ Elem(null, head, null, TopScope), rest = tail))

      case Nil => processor
    }

  def toXml(input: List[String]): NodeSeq = toXml(Processor(Nil, input)).value


scala> toXml(list).toString
res28: String = <a></a><b></b><b></b><span><b></b><d></d><span><d></d><a></a></span></span><b></b><a></a><span><b></b></span><a></a><b></b>
```

Comment: The other responses where useful, but I ended up going with a variation of this solution.  I was able to add other attributes to the case object that helped me keep track of other information in a purely functional way (my post was a simplified version of my real project).
Thank you very much everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Synesso's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45525/synesso) idea of using `foldLeft`. You just need to keep track of how many nesting levels you have.

```
val cN = """c(\d+)""".r
def encode(l: List[String]) = l.foldLeft("" -> 0) {
    case ((acc, nesting), "ce")      => (acc + "</span>" * nesting, 0)
    case ((acc, nesting), cN(style)) =>
        (acc + """<span style="%s">""".format(style), nesting + 1)
    case ((acc, nesting), el)        => (acc + "<%s/>".format(el), nesting)
}._1
```

This returns a `String`, which you can easily convert later to `XML`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that list didn't just come to exist in isolation, it began as lines in a file, or a string of comma-separated values, or some other format - You then split it as appropriate to generate the list.

Instead of doing that, you could start with the original input and then rephrase the question:

> Given this raw input, how can I process it to produce the following
>   tree structure?
>
> *(which I'll be outputting as XML)*

To which the answer is "use Scala's Parsers", which will give you some beautifully declarative code.  You'll also find it easier to maintain than anything you roll yourself.